# Reading a file with no extension in a zip file

Tags: java

I am struggling to find a solution reading a zip file .The zip has a file with stringified JSON but there is no extension to the file.

I tried using the API ZipInputStream part of the package java.util.zip.ZipInputStream ,however the code never goes into the Sysout mentioned below in the code

```
InputStream initialStream = new FileInputStream(
                new File("D:\\test_data.zip"));
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(initialStream);
        try {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.printf("File: %s Size %d Modified on %TD %n", entry.getName(), entry.getSize(),
                        new Date(entry.getTime()));
            }
        } finally {
            zipInputStream.close();
        }
```

Comment: What error message do you get?  AFAIK the extension of the file should not matter so long as it is a ZIP archive.  Maybe you wanted `new File("D:\\test_data")` ?

Comment: Side note - if you're using Java 7, you should probably use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of putting the `close` in a finally block.

Comment: @Tim there is no error

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Can you successfully open this ZIP archive using a tool like 7-Zip? and 2) Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen: Yes I can open the file through the 7zip , it is a file without extension , while trying to edit in notepad++ I can see the content as a JSON. Through code trying out my luck

Comment: What is the name of the contained file? I ask because `ZipInputStream` expects the names encoded in UTF-8, but many zip utilities encode filenames with CP1252 or similar encodings. That would mean that `getNextEntry()` would throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.